# Along with Predictive probability and class name how to get the text(s) belonging to that class in text analytics problem

Tags: python, machine-learning

Assuming `Humpty Dumpty` is text trained under given specific model belonging to class called "cartoon character" in multi-text classification model.

```
model.predict_proba([Invoice_parameter])*100 
# gives the probability of belongings to specific class.
```

But how come I can retrieve the text for that probability hit for that class.

For example,

```
Invoice_parameter= input() ---- on the fly input

"Humpty Dumpty sat on the wall"

model.predict_proba([Invoice_parameter])*100
```

I get probability of 99.98 (rounded to two decimal places) to Character class but I also need to retrieve the text `Humpty Dumpty`.

Exactly I am looking for the text which points to the class as identified by the model.

"Humpty Dumpty sat on the wall"

when above statement fed to the pre-trained/saved model it returns the class output as `Character`.

Also I want the text part which trained for that respective class. Assuming `Humpty Dumpty` is trained under `Character` class.

Here I am using pre-trained model and `Invoice_parameter` is the input I am passing like `Humpty Dumpty sat on the wall`:

```
import pandas as pd
Class_Predictive_Prob=pd.DataFrame(model.predict_proba([Invoice_parameter])*100, columns=model.classes_)

print("Class with predictive probability",Class_Predictive_Prob.max(axis=0))

Output for Multi-Class Text Classification problem
_________
Class with predictive probability

Movies       0.000015
Character    99.980123
Drama        0.000008
So on..
```

I am looking for output which looks like:

```
Class followed by the probability hit and the text part giving that hit

Output for Multi-Class Text Classification problem
_________
Class with predictive probability
```

Character    99.980123 Humpty Dumpty

Answer (score 0):

What you implemented sounds like text classification (classifying the whole text) but what you want sounds like entity recognition (classifying on the token level). You can still build a model that does both (Multitask Learning) but you need labeled data for both tasks (labels not only on the text but labels also on the token level).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a model interpretation. Basically you need the features that influenced positively for the predicted class.

There is an excellent package [`eli5`](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which provides this functionality for Sklearn machine learning models.

Look at the text explanier example [here](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_notebooks/text-explainer.html#textexplainer), which pretty close to your expectation.

[image]

The terms highlighted in green are the ones, which is responsible for the hit!